# PHP - Can't seem to upload files

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I know that there are a lot of duplicates but I just can't figure out why i'm getting these errors, so maybe one of you knows?

Here is my code:

```
//Uploading and handling second file
    $target_dir = "images/uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['game-team-pic']['name']);

    $stmt4 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO gamefotos (fotoNaam, fotoCaption, fotoPath, gameNr) VALUES (:game_team_pic, :game_team_desc, :foto_path, :id)");

    $stmt4->bindParam(':game_team_pic', $team_pic);
    $stmt4->bindParam(':game_team_desc', $team_desc);
    $stmt4->bindParam(':foto_path', $target_file);
    $stmt4->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt4->execute();

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['game-team-pic']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/uploads/game-2.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\PhpStorm\Projects\Gamesite\php\auth-functions.php on line 64

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Users\mauri\AppData\Local\Temp\php7F8A.tmp' to 'images/uploads/game-2.jpg' in D:\PhpStorm\Projects\Gamesite\php\auth-functions.php on line 64
```

Can anyone help me?
Would be very much appreciated

Comment: `images/uploads/` might not exist in the program current working directory. Try an absolute path.

Comment: It's either `game-banner` or `game-team-pic` which is it?  Probably `game-banner`...

Comment: So sat like "D:\PhpStorm\Projects\Gamesite"
And then add "images/uploads/"
So it then becomes "D:\PhpStorm\Projects\Gamesite\images\uploads\"

Comment: @AbraCadaver Didn't notice that one, thank you. I will edit my answer.
Unfortunaly That didn't fix it for me tho

Comment: @stickybit Changed it to what I mentioned above, although I'm not getting an error anymore. It's also not appearing in my uploads folder